# NodeJS end event with while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, sax

I try to iterate this big xml file using [sax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax), here is the code:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const sax = require('sax');

let rowsAdded = 0;
let rows = [];
let options = {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    mode: 0o444
};
let strict = true,
feedFile = 'Comments.xml',
saxStream = sax.createStream(strict);
saxStream.on('opentag', node => {
    if(rowsAdded === 5) {
        return saxStream.end();
    }
    // I only need nodes named 'row'
    if(node.name === 'row') {
        rowsAdded++;
        // If the name is 'row' and `attribute` prop exists, push it. 
        if(node.attributes) rows.push(node.attributes);
    }
})
.on('error', () => {
})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Done reading:', rowsAdded);
    // If you remove this while loop the above console will called only once
    while(rowsAdded--) {

    }
});
fs.createReadStream(feedFile, options).pipe(saxStream);
```

The `console.log` will log `Done reading: 5` around **43** times, if I comment out the while loop, it will only console `Done reading: 5` **once!**, am I doing something wrong?, is it a bug?

Comment: Don't know, but I would guess it has to do with the `rowsAdded++`. Should there be a `return` statement after the `saxStream.end()` call?

Comment: @squint A return will just prevent the continuing of the callback(it's a good point), but same behavior :(

Comment: Why do you call saxStream.end() explicitly? It should be triggered automatically once the stream has finished. If you keep it running (while) and not let it to finish and return, the streaming will continue...

Comment: @AvielFedida, what is your goal? To read the 1st 5 tags only or to read the whole xml?

Comment: @dsdenes I need to stop incoming chunks, I know it's not the only way nor the best but it works, the rows array will contain 5 elements, there is only this problem.

Comment: @Gavriel The system will be more flexible, the xml file is about 11 GB, for now I'm just trying stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return from saxStream.on('opentag') it means that you finished working on that tag, but the parser continues until it finishes the whole xml.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation, but is the continuing of the calls is due to the buffer wasn't empty yet, I mean is the `end` is kind of `sax` saying I already have a buffer, let me finish parsing it, and I will stop calling `opentag` callback(stop the parser)?

Comment: The second I got is that it just taking time for `end` chain to actually stop the stream, I looked at the source code but I can't say.

Comment: actually in the documentation it says that there's a close() method, but nothing about end(), however you are right, it says: "close - Close the stream. Once closed, no more data may be written until it is done processing the **buffer**, which is signaled by the end event."

Answer (score 2):

So you want to pause a Readable stream in the moment when you need to continue data pipeline. That's why the `shutdown` function should be out of the pipeline's scope, where you can simply pause it as `readable.pause` inside `done` function.

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const sax = require('sax');

let rowsAdded = 0;
let rows = [];
let options = {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    mode: 0o444
};
let strict = true,
feedFile = 'Comments.xml',
saxStream = sax.createStream(strict);
saxStream.on('opentag', node => {
    // I only need nodes named 'row'
    if(node.name === 'row' && rowsAdded < 5) {
        rowsAdded++;
        // If the name is 'row' and `attribute` prop exists, push it. 
        if(node.attributes) rows.push(node.attributes);
    }
    if(rowsAdded === 5)
        done();
})
.on('error', () => {
})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Done reading:', rowsAdded);
});

var readable = fs.createReadStream(feedFile, options)
readable.pipe(saxStream);

function done(){
    // this should stop reading part.
    readable.pause();
    while(rowsAdded--) {
        // do you processing here
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @AvielFedida  I'm glad it helped. Next time elaborate a little bit on your motivation and what you want to achieve by the code, it helps to get you the answer you need. Cheers!

Comment: It usually makes an answer better and quicker to understand if you can add some textual description of what the fix you made was rather than just leave it to the reader to try to figure out what you changed in the code and why.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, thanks. I planned to do so, didn't expect that it initially would fit the initial requirements of author ;)